# Chrome displaying random characters

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

Every once in a while I land on a web page with bizarrely random text (see accompanying screenshot, from https://minnie.tuhs.org/CompArch/Resources/mips_quick_tutorial.html).  I'm on an M2 Macbook and my default browser is Chrome.  Sometimes, like today, I can get the correct rendering by trying either Firefox or Safari.  And before you suggest the obvious, note that I switched from Firefox to Chrome because Firefox was my default browser when I first experienced this behavior.

So, Is there likely to be a preference somewhere, like "display text correctly"? (oops, my snarky side showed itself)